# PDF text selection on iOS

Tags: ios, pdf

I'm looking for ways to implement text selection over a parsed PDF in iOS. I already have the positions of all the glyphs by using the Quartz PDF parsing functions, but I don't know of a good way to implement the selection of the text without writing the selection logic and view  from scratch (And display it either in the view displaying the pdf or in some transparent overlay view).

The experience should be similar to selecting text in a UITextField or UIWebView (for example).

Existing 3rd party solutions which I could integrate would be best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the [Omni framework](http://www.omnigroup.com/company/developer/), which implements a similar selection.

Comment: How exactly does your solution look like? What did you gt out of the framework?

Comment: If you can share more, that would be great.

Comment: can you check the link?